# mongodb query to get documents created before a given time

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, timestamp

I am trying to get all the documents which were created after a given time, lets say t = 'Saturday, September 2nd, 2017, 3:07:48 PM', so i should get all documents which were created before 2/09/2017,3:07:48 PM.

Here is my database schema:

```
{
  author: 'abc', //String
  createdAt: 'Monday, August 14th, 2017, 9:46:09 PM', // String
  title: 'How to code' // String
 }
```

I used follwoing query for same but i am getting random documents which do not follow the above required time constraint.

```
post.find({createdAt:{$lt:req.params.time}}, function(err,posts){
      if(err) return res.json({Status:Failed});
      if(posts){
         return res.json(posts);
      }
      else{
          return res.json({
          msg: 'Could not find older posts',
          });
      }
   });
```

am i using wrong time stamp format in the query?

Comment: What type is `createdAt` ?

Comment: i have updated datatypes, all of them are string types.

Comment: so you have your own answer, you cannot compare dates using theirs string representation as you described. You gotta either change the type of field to `Date`, or use a tricky way to achieve your goal

Comment: so i need to define my custom function to parse string time to some format and then use in the query? Since i can not update datatype of createdAt field. I was looking for some other alternative way.

Comment: i think i have got an alternative sol. i can use auto created _id since it contains datetime info of creation embedded in it.

Comment: well you can, it's gonna be better than use this awfull field. Because the field gonna have 0 good indexing and the custom function execution gonna be needy